# Weird uninitialized const member behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Consider this code snippet:

```
struct Foo {

};

template<typename T>
struct Bar {
    const T foo;
};

int main() {
    Bar<Foo> test;
}
```

I'm compiling it with g++-4.9.2 with [-std=c++11 -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion] and getting `error: uninitialized const member in ‘struct Bar<Foo>’`. This is pretty obvious.

BUT try just add std::string as Foo member and program compiles!

```
#include <string>
struct Foo {
    std::string test;
};
// (...)
```

What happening? Replacing test's type into double causes program to fail to compile again. What string member changes in class?

[Link to online compiler with this snippet.](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXATuA5gPgChDMsYIMkAxAexqQG9CBICGsTJTOALh9LxIMCTAG5CAX3GFhAWwAOUAIbCUGAJ7yEYJbOQAVIqXKUAQkqyMWbDpX1IAZnXFTi4SrKXgAFAEorzOZYKLQ0%2BEIiGC5AA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fopt%2Fgcc-4.9.0%2Fbin%2Fg%2B%2B%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O2%20-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%22%7D%5D%7D)

It seems that gcc behaves like that since version 4.6.

Comment: Seems to be a GCC bug clang does not share: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/508312aef603cc15

Comment: I initiality though that it is some missing warning but adding [-O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion] doesn't give any more compiler messages.

Comment: MSVC does not exhibit the problem either and refuses to compile for lack of default constructor.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it should consistently always produce an error. Clang does so. The C++ standard says in clause (4.3) of §12.1.4 that
the default constructor is implicitly deleted when

> — any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or
>   array thereof) with no brace-or equal-initializer does not have a
>   user-provided default constructor,

As `Foo` does not have a user-provided default constructor, `Bar` should have an implicitly deleted default constructor and thus instantiating `Bar<Foo> test` in main should produce an error.

Maybe report a bug to GCC?

Answer (score 4):

If you have `const` data member in your class/struct, then compiler won't generate default constructor for that. You have to explicitly define it and initialize that `const` member ( not assign it ).

It should be an error in both cases.

Comment: This is not answering the question. Why does it compile if an `std::string` data member is added to `Foo`.

Comment: `Bar` has a `const` data member `Foo`.

Comment: @ravi: constness of added to `Foo` string parameter doesn't matter. `Bar` has `const Foo`.

Comment: It is an error in both case (Apple LLVM 6.0) for me. You can not define a const variable without initialize it, and the default construtor canoot be applied in such a case, you need to define a ctor with no paramter in `Foo` class.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like g++ automatically generates a default constructor even when const members should have been initialized at construction time because it knows that a string has a default constructor initializing it to an empty string. In fact all happens as if the source was :

```
struct Foo {
    std::string test;
    Foo():test() {;}
};

template<typename T>
struct Bar {
    const T foo;
    Bar(): foo() {;}
};

int main() {
    Bar<Foo> test;
}
```

which compiles fine both with clang and MSVC.

(but I must admit I still haven't found the reference in gcc doc explaining that ...)